# Add smooth transition to div sorting using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have made a sorting of divs using jquery and added a bit of transition.

The transition works when the first div takes the place of second div but it doesn't work when the second div takes place of first div.

Is there any way it can be done in both ways.

jQuery code:

```
$("body").on('click tap', '.sort-arrows .fa-arrow-down', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var pos = $(this).parent().index();
  var elem = $(this).closest("div").parent();
  if (elem.index() <= (elem.siblings('div').length - 1)) {
    elem.fadeOut('slow', function() {
      elem.insertAfter(elem.next('div')).fadeIn('slow');
    });
  }

});
$("body").on('click tap', '.sort-arrows .fa-arrow-up', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var pos = $(this).parent().index();
  var elem = $(this).closest("div").parent();
  if (elem.index() > 0) {
    elem.fadeOut('slow', function() {
      elem.insertBefore(elem.prev('div')).fadeIn('slow');
    });
  }
});
```

Demo -- https://jsfiddle.net/gvyoj63a/6/

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: Question is not clear. Please explain how second div taking the place of first div does not work? I just tried on jsfiddle. If I click top arrow on second div, it does take the place of first div.

Comment: Sorry @yakutsa for replying late. The sorting works ie shifting the position of div elements. But if you notice then the transition works only when the first div takes the place of second div but not when second div goes upward. I am talking about the transition for second div going upward if you click down arrow for first div. Hope it clears. Thanks.